# How to add same object type as different tables in same realm?

Tags: ios, realm

I'm using realm to cache certain network data coming down which is specific to the last search.  I'd also like to be able to star or pin this data to save it for future usage.  The data objects are exactly the same and I can't find anything in the documentation that allows me to save them in separate tables in Realm.

Comment: Consider using separate realm for caching. Anyway at some point you must provide separate name for "table" as the same success it could be different db.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to go about doing this would be to simply create a subclass of your model object with a different name (e.g., `MyDataObject` and its subclass `MySavedDataObject`). This will create a new table in the Realm database file with the same schema and will let you distinguish between the two types of objects.

You can then create a copy of a normal object as a saved object as simply as the following:

```
let myNewSavedObject = MySavedDataObject(value: myDataObject)
```

That all being said, instead of duplicating data, I would personally recommend being a bit more efficient with the existing data set. Surely simply adding an additional boolean property to the schema named something like `saved` would let you simply mark objects that you wish to keep without needing a whole second table. :)

Comment: Marking another field on the object as saved was the first approach. The problem is that this data is all coming from the network so the field "saved" isn't really approach to that particular model object. I wanted to just model the network model.  Additionally, once I change my search criteria I'll be pulling different data at that point to be cached so ideally none of this data would be staying around.  Which is why I wanted to save particular results to another area to be held onto.

Comment: I'm not a fan of subclassing without introducing explicit additional behavior but I might try that next.  I didn't know of the convenience method in order to do it.  Was trying copy() before so I'll try it out.