# How can I save data in different table with same model in Realm | Swift / SwiftUI

Tags: swift, realm

How can I save data in different table with same model with Realm I am using Realm and Unrealm.

I use the Question model when saving the selected questions and again when saving the wrong questions I save the Question model. However, when I fetch the wrong questions after saving the wrong questions, the fetch occurs with the selected questions.

**Console:**

````
wrongQuestions: [```"50"```, ```"50"```, "49", "48", "47", "46", "45", "44", "43", "42", "41", "40", "39", "38", "37", "36", "35", "34", "33", "32", "31", "30", "29", "28", "27", "26", "25", "24", "23", "22", "21", "20", "19", "18", "17", "16", "15", "14", "13", "12", "11", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
````

As seen in the console array has two ids 50. I just want to bring up the wrong questions. How can I open a separate table in Realm? or what should i do?

**My Models:**

```
struct QuizContainer: Codable, Realmable, Hashable {
    var allQuiz: [Quiz] = []
}

struct Quiz: Codable, Realmable, Hashable {
    var id: String = ""
    var questions: [Question] = []
    var title: String = ""
    
    static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}

struct Question: Codable, Realmable, Hashable {
    
    var id: String = ""
    var question: String = ""
    var imageURL: String = ""
    var sections: [String : String] = [:]
    var correct: String = ""
    var isQuestionImage: Bool = false
    var isSectionImage: Bool = false
    var selected: String = ""
}
```

**Functions:**

```
func saveWronQuestionToRealm(wrongQuestion: Question) {
    guard let realmReferance = try? Realm() else { return }
    do {
        try realmReferance.write({
            realmReferance.add(wrongQuestion)
        })
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
}

func getWrongQuestionFromToRealm() -> [Question]? {
    if let realmReferance = try? Realm() {
        let resultQuiz = realmReferance.objects(Question.self).reversed()
        let wrongQuestion = resultQuiz.compactMap { category in
            return category
        }
        return wrongQuestion
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The question and what's you're trying to do is a bit unclear. But... why do you need to save the same type of data in two tables? Why not just add a property to your question model 'is_wrong' and set it to true when it's a wrong question? Also, what is the purpose of `getWrongQuestionFromToRealm`? Lastly, taking a look at your data, it seems to be corrupted and the question 50 is stored like this '''"50"''' whereas the rest are stored like this `"49"`. Oh, and there's nothing stopping two or more questions having the same id. A `var id: String = "" type is not guaranteed unique

Comment: I used ```50``` to specify the same id. only the wrong questions will be saved and then the user will be able to view the wrong questions from the categories in the main menu. 
getWrongQuestionFromToRealm: function that allows to return questions that are wrong

Comment: Really not sure what's being asked here. Would love to help but its really unclear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35145213/how-to-add-same-object-type-as-different-tables-in-same-realm actually looks like the problem here. But I did not understand the solution.

Comment: No, that question is a totally different use case. You can have as many Realms as you want. But again, it's completely unclear why you need separate Realms (Realms are not tables) instead of just adding a flag to the wrong questions. Opening a realm at a different location or with a different name is covered thoroughly in the documentation [Open A Local Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/examples/configure-and-open-a-realm/#open-a-local-realm)